# Memory Error while running python script on 4GB file

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am trying to count number of words that has length between 1 and 5, file size is around 4GB end I am getting memory error.

```
import os 
files = os.listdir('C:/Users/rram/Desktop/') 
for file_name in files:     
    file_path = "C:/Users/rram/Desktop/"+file_name     
    f = open (file_path, 'r')    
    text = f.readlines()
    update_text = '' 
    wordcount = {}
    for line in text:         
        arr = line.split("|")
        word = arr[13]
        if 1<=len(word)<6:
            if word not in wordcount:
                wordcount[word] = 1
        else:
            wordcount[word] += 1
            update_text+= '|'.join(arr)
print (wordcount)     #print update_text
print 'closing', file_path, '\t', 'total files' , '\n\n'
f.close()
```

At the end i get a `MemoryError` on this line `text = f.readlines()`

Can you pelase help to optimize it.

Comment: delete this line `text = f.readlines()` you can iterate over the file handle

Comment: Can you please correct the indentation ?

Comment: You should iterate over the lines like `for line in f:`. Don't overload your memory reading all of the file at once.

Comment: Sorry, indentation moved out when copy pasting. @MohamedALANI

Comment: can i use f.readline() , for faster output since it loaded into memory and performs the operation.

Answer (score 3):

As suggested in the comments you should read the file line by line and not the entire file.

For example :

```
count = 0
with open('words.txt','r') as f:
    for line in f:
        for word in line.split():
          if(1 <= len(word) <=5):
              count=count+1
print(count)
```

**EDIT :**

If you only want to count the words in 14-th column and split by `|` instead then :

```
count = 0
with open('words.txt','r') as f:
    for line in f:
        iterator = 0
        for word in line.split("|"):
            if(1 <= len(word) <=5 and iterator == 13):
                count=count+1
            iterator = iterator +1
print(count)
```

note that you should avoid to write this

```
arr = line.split("|")
word = arr[13]
```

since the line may contains less than 14 words, which can result in a segmentation error.

Comment: In my file there are many records and in each record fields are separated by |, and i am particularly looking at the column number 14.

Comment: @FlorentJousse: if you are concerned, that `arr` has not enough elements, use `count += len(arr) >= 13 and 1 <= len(arr[13]) <= 5`

Comment: Dear @FlorentJousse , i am sure my records have length more than 14, there are around 70 columnns and if no data is there just pipes are available.like |||||||||.  Thank you very much. Is their any other advantage of Iterator int the above code?